# How could I connect to AWS Windows EC2 using RDP?

Tags: rdp, aws-ec2

I have some question about connect using RDP with Windows EC2.
I create two EC2 instances: one is Windows 2016 platform, and the other one is Arch Linux.
I also create one VPC with allow any connection.

I believe that the VPC is correct because of successful connection to Arch Linux. But why I couldn't RDP to the Windows EC2?

Anyone has any idea?

I can get the screenshot of monitor and trouble shooting.

As the below:

[Instance summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jneY.png)

[Instance network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RriS1.jpg)

[VPC-NACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQz4T.png)

[VPC-Routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc9Sb.png)

[Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a5O4.png)

[Error message for Microsoft Remote Desktop on MAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQsIH.png)

PS. I created the EC2 with AMI: "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 with Desktop Experience Locale English AMI provided by Amazon".

AMI ID: ami-0bc64185df5784cc3

---

The result for reachability Analyzer:

[Windows to Linux port 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Pj2.png): Success.

[Linux to Windows port 3389](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTBAt.png): Success.

Comment: show the error message

Comment: `I believe that the VPC is correct because of successful connection to Arch Linux.` It isn't. Also, the "screen shot" you provided is not useful.

Comment: Please specify the error, there are many checks to be done: reachability (internet or private), networks (routes, IGW, NAT), access (security group, NACL)...

Comment: Now I can connect the EC2 with RDP tools. But I don't know why if I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is if you enabled RDP connection to your Windows VM, also if 3389 port is allowed directly on Windows VM. Dont see what else can be causing you the problem.

Comment: I created the VM using AMI image, so I didn't know how to check if RDP is enabled.

Comment: You can connect to EC2 via EC2 Serial Console and after you connect you can check firewall and if RDP is enabled

Comment: I changed the VM type to t3 for supporting EC2 serial console. But I can't see any thing on the screen.